# Prevent task from being scheduled

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

I have a `sysfs` interface which when written to should prevent the writing task from executing until certain conditions are met.

The condition for unblocking is of the form:

```
if(tsk->wait_time > MAX_WAIT_PERIOD || tsk->condition_met) {
    // Unblock task and let it run again
}
```

Because of the nature of the condition, I don't think `schedule_timeout` is the right mechanism to use; or at least, I haven't figured out how to use it and then cancel the wait time / appropriately signal the process.

I have also tried manually doing the following on the `sysfs` write:

```
...
__set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
schedule();
...
```

And then when the condition is satisfied:

```
if(tsk->wait_time > MAX_WAIT_PERIOD || tsk->condition_met) {
    set_task_state(tsk, TASK_RUNNING);
}
```

This results in: `BUG: scheduling while atomic: dummyThread/2622/0x00000002`
Given how, `schedule_timeout` does *almost* the exact same logic, I suspect that it would also cause the same `BUG: scheduling while atomic: ...` error.

I have also tried the `deactivate_task` and `activate_task` methods, but they cause a kernel panic in the scheduler's `pick_next_task` chain. If required, I will re-implement this and post the stack trace.

What is the right way to prevent a task from running until certain conditions are met?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but from what i understand , your user space process trying to write should be unable to write again before you allow it to. If so , why no block the I/O in the write method ? that way you block the writer until your condition is met , could be data available or whatever. It seems a bit strange to manually change the task state knowing that the I/O operation (the write) is already allowed to block unless O_NONBLOCK is specified ? Then a simple semaphore would work ?

Comment: I agree. It should have been straightforward. However, acquiring a semaphore would in turn eventually lead to a call to `schedule()` which would, in my case, cause the `BUG: scheduling while atomic: ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`schedule_timeout()` is good low-level function for timed wait.

But `set_task_state()` is bad choice for wake up: this function is mainly for *current* thread. Instead, use `wake_up_process` or `wake_up_state`.

Comment: This works! It turns out that the boiler plate code that I borrowed from another function in `fs/proc/base.c` had me calling my `schedule_timeout` logic within `get_proc_task()` and `task_lock()`. Once I moved my code outside of this, things worked without causing `BUG: scheduling while atomic: ...`